# “got off wrong”: What does it mean?

Tags: meaning

I heard this in a movie:

> "We got off wrong".

What is the meaning of *"got off wrong"*?

I tried looking it up via Google, but I couldn’t find anything about it.

Comment: I have the subtitles of over 1000 movies, and neither **got offwrong** nor **got off wrong** occur even once, so I think this is Too Localised. @MD: it's not at all standard English to say *"We got off wrong"* - the normal version is *"We got off **badly**"*. But note that the common idiom is *"We got off **on the wrong foot**"*. Whimsically changed to *"We got off on the wrong **boot**"* by Dr. King Schultz in Django Unchained, since his character isn't a native English speaker either.

Comment: Could you mean "oft-wrong," where "oft" is short for "often"? http://www.thefreedictionary.com/oft

Comment: It would be helpful to have some context for this phrase.  Can you remember some more of the dialogue or what the movie was?  FumbleFingers suggestion of "we got off on the wrong foot" is good - it means "we started badly" or "we did not like each other at first".  But maybe you heard something quite different.  A common English phrase is "We got along" which means (more or less) "We quite liked each other".

Comment: @FumbleFingers : "We got off-wrong" that's what [Nick Moran](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0602941/) says when [Jennifer Esposito](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0261170/) is leaving [Michael Kopsa's](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0465959/) office in the movie : [The Proposal(2001)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0179435/)..... Please correct me , if I'm wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly suspect this is simply saying one of these:

> We got off to the wrong start.
>
> We started off on the wrong foot.

Per the OED, *to start/get off on the wrong foot* means

> to start unsuccessfully; to fail to establish good relations.

Comment: Thanks..... but, they think, they didn't hear it , any where..... I heard this, in [this](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0179435/) movie.